# How do I limit my search to a particular package or module with Hoogle?

Tags: haskell, hoogle

I remember reading that you can limit your search query to a particular module or package. But I can't seem to find anything on Google.

Comment: Here's the [Hoogle documentation](https://github.com/ndmitchell/hoogle/blob/master/README.md#scope) on how to do it.

Comment: Thanks, just found that!

Comment: You can also use stackage which allows you to search within the package from that particular packages's index page.

Answer (score 0):

From https://wiki.haskell.org/Hoogle#Searches:

> Packages: Searches can be restricted to a particular package with
>   +packagename, or to avoid a package with -package. By default Hoogle will search a standard set of packages.

Example: `get +scotty`